# What kind of geometric object does $3x^2+4y^2-12x+8y+17z=0$ represent?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am given the following equation $$3x^2+4y^2-12x+8y+17z=0$$ and I have to find what kind of geometric object this is.

I don't think this is a sphere because I can't find the radius or the center from the given information. And I also don't think that this is a cylindrical surface because it contains all the variables $x$, $y$, and $z$. But I may be wrong.

Could you please explain what this is? Thank you very much

Comment: What is the shape if $z$ is fixed? Then try to vary $z$.

Comment: Try to play around with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ziab2rjpan

Comment: It is an elliptical paraboloid.

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/xeaem43a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's an elliptic parabloid.

I think if you complete the square you will get something more decipherable like this:

$$3(x-2)^2 +4(y+1)^2 +17z -16 = 0$$

Comment: I think $-16$ rather than $+16$, right? The quadratic terms contribute $+16$, so you will need a constant term of $-16$ to recover the original equation. Still, +1 for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for catching the error!

Answer (score 2):

It is elliptical paraboloid:

- For each fixed $z\leq {16\over 17}$ you get an ellipse:

$$3(x-2)^2 + 4(y+1)^2 = 16-17z$$

- For each fixed $x$ or $y$ you get a parabola.

Answer (score 2):

It is an elliptic paraboloid.

If you know the canonical equation of an elliptic paraboloid, you can show this by completing the square.

Comment: When I complete the square I get an extra _16_ as a constant, but in the formula for elliptic paraboloid there is no constant...or does that just mean that it is moved 16 units up?

Comment: @Britanica In this case, $16/17$ units up

Comment: @Britanica You can make a change of variables if you want to write it in the form $Z=X^2/a^2+Y^2/b^2$. What gt6989b says is right.

Comment: @A.Goodier  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`Mathematica` image

p = 7 ;  ContourPlot3D[
3 x^2 + 4 y^2 - 12 x + 8 y + 17 z = = 0, {x, -p, p}, {y, -p,
p}, {z, -p, p}]

Could be reducible to form

$$\dfrac{z}{c} =  1 -\dfrac{( x-p)^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{ (y-q)^2}{b^2} ...$$

***Elliptic paraboloid*** as the sections parallel to axes are ellipses, parabolas..

[image]